# Trying to smoothly/continuously animate a sine wave link underline on hover with CSS / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

Example here:

```js
$(function(){
        var x = 0;
        setInterval(function(){
            x-=1;
            $(".link-wavy:hover").css('background-position', x + 'px 100%');
        }, 20);
    })
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  font-weight: 400;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.link-contact {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #000;
}

.link-wavy {
  padding-bottom: 9px;
  background-image: url("http://uploads.webflow.com/56d8a8f1100bc1bb7928eebd/5831d10096c13a1f491ac02d_wavy-k.png");
  background-position: -50px 100%;
  background-size: 230px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="link-contact w-inline-block" href="http://google.com">
    <div class="link-wavy">wavvvvvvy baby</div>
  </a>
```

It's got the right idea.. moving the background image continuously on hover so the wave moves.

But I'm not very proficient in jQuery, and I'd love it to be a little more refined...

Ideally the sine wave motion would have some ease in-out on hover, and 'start' where it stops on hover out (so there isn't a jump reset to the original position when hovering over).

Any ideas are hugely appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

For info, animation CSS is fine to this :

example

```css
.link-wavy {
  animation: wavit 2s linear infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}
.link-wavy:hover {
  animation-play-state: running;
}
@keyframes wavit {
  to {
    background-position: 100% 100%;
  }
}


body {
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  font-weight: 400;
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

/* added some flex instead absolute + transform */
html,
body {
  display: flex;/* to center demo */
}
.link-contact {
  margin: auto;/* flex item centers itself */
  color: #000;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.link-wavy {
  padding-bottom: 9px;
  background-image: url("http://uploads.webflow.com/56d8a8f1100bc1bb7928eebd/5831d10096c13a1f491ac02d_wavy-k.png");
  background-position: 0 100%;
  background-size: 230px;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<a class="link-contact w-inline-block" href="http://google.com">
  <div class="link-wavy">wavvvvvvy baby</div>
</a>
```

Comment: Love that, thanks! I can probably figure out how to add easing to this. Although it seems to jump at the end of the loop. Any idea why that is?

Comment: If it jumps at the end of the line you have to adjust the background-size. However you would probably face the same issue on a dynamic content.